# `terraform validate` fails on GitHub Action with obscure error message

Tags: terraform, github-actions

Our GitHub Action performing `terraform validate` fails with an obscure error message:

```
Run terraform validate -no-color
/home/runner/work/_temp/12cb240b-5a9f-44d7-9df4-0c2e0c97750d/terraform-bin validate -no-color
/home/runner/work/_temp/12cb240b-5a9f-44d7-9df4-0c2e0c97750d/terraform:4211
  core.setOutput('exitcode', exitCode.toString(10));
                                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toString')
    at /home/runner/work/_temp/12cb240b-5a9f-44d7-9df4-0c2e0c97750d/terraform:4211:39
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Here is our `.github/workflows/terraform_pr.yml`:

```
name: Terraform PR Check

on: [pull_request]

jobs:
  terraform:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: HashiCorp - Setup Terraform
        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v2
        with:
          terraform_version: 1.3.4


      - name: Terraform fmt
        id: fmt
        run: terraform fmt -check -recursive

      - name: Terraform Init
        id: init
        run: terraform init -backend=false

      - name: Terraform Validate
        id: validate
        run: terraform validate -no-color
```

A commit from two months ago passed the *Terraform PR Check* successfully.
Today, I created a test branch based on that commit and created a PR for this branch.
My test branch differs from the old commit by a text file named `foo.txt` containing the string "hello world".

Unfortunately, the PR for the test branch failed with the same error message above as the branch I am actually working on.
Therefore, I believe this to be an issue with Terraform and/or GitHub Actions.
Could someone please offer advice on how to solve this issue?

Comment: That stack trace is an error from JS and not Go so this would be root cause in the `setup-terraform` GH action. You should probably check the version retrieved from two months ago versus the version retrieved in the recent GH action execution. Then, if you are fully confident in the delta only being the version retrieved, you would probably want to file an issue on its tracker.

Comment: Thanks! It seems the problem is indeed related to `setup-terraform`.

Comment: I configured the `setup-terraform` GH action to not install its wrapper script and could then see that terraform exits with status code 137. I assume it's being killed due to resource limits by GH.